# Calculate the area of the graph of the function $f(x,y) = xy$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem says:

> Calculate the area of the graph of the function $f: D \to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x,y) = xy$, and D is the unit circle.

My thoughts on this problem is that the graph of a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$, but not sure how to follow. This question comes from a Second Year final exam in a Math career. Any help?

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 2):

We start by calculating the area-element $dA$, which for graphs of functions are:
$$dA=\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}dxdy=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

Thus the area you are looking for is:
$$A = \int_D dA = \int_D\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r\sqrt{1+r^2}drd\theta = 2\pi\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{3} \right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the change of coordinates (do not forget the jacobian):
$$x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta$$
As our area is the unit circle then $r\in[0,1]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. So
$$A=\int\int_{D}xy\;dxdy=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta \;drd\theta=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin\theta\cos\theta\;d\theta=0$$
That make sense knowing the graph of the function

Comment: The graph of the function $f$ is a two-dimensional surface in $\Bbb R^3$, and unless I am mistaken, its area is not $\iint_D f(x, y)dxdy$, and is not zero.

Comment: I really misunderstood the question, hahaha, i thought he was asking about the integral of that function over the domain D

Answer (score -1):

Note that $f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)$ and since the unit circle is symmetric with respect to reflection over the y-axis, the area is 0

Comment: The graph of the function $f$ is a two-dimensional surface in $\Bbb R^3$, and unless I am mistaken, its area is not $\iint_D f(x, y)dxdy$, and is not zero.